# Response in laravel component

Tags: php, laravel

I have a component `SeenRecentlyProduct` and return code:

```
return response()->view('components.products.seen-recently-product', compact('seenRecentlyProducts'))
    ->withCookie($cookie);
```

I get an error:

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

If I write this code in the controller, it works well. If I remove `response()` from the component, the same works well. Help please resolve the issue with the response and cookie in the component.